# get class value of element from css

Tags: html, css

I have html with tables. background color of a table cell is specified in a attribute 'class'. e.g.:

```
 <td class="bg_red">red-bg</td>
 <td class="bg_blue">blud-bg</td>
```

one way of resolving this is in css file specify like this:

```
td.bg_red {background-color: red;}
td.bg_blue {background-color: blue;}
```

I would like to make it more dynamic. is there a way in css file to parse these class values so that I can specify it something like this:

```
td[class^="bg_"]{
    background-color: *PARSED VALUE*;
}
```

will appreciate your help.

regards,
rnv

Comment: ok.. thanks for the info... got it that it cannot be done.

Answer (score 0):

Not in vanilla CSS, but you can use a preprocessor like SASS! They're awesome. Here's a link.

http://sass-lang.com/

SASS allows you to use stuff like **variables**, and nested CSS. I think what you need is a variable for your background colors. Have fun.

Comment: What the OP wants isn't really solvable using a preprocessor. Oh it can create loops and mixins but it still outputs **CSS** at the end. What **CSS** can't do is parse a class and apply properties based on the text of the classname.

Comment: Yup you're right. I'll leave the answer here though, I think it adds value thanks to the explanation that you just gave :P